# TCP server hangs, not responding to SYN

Tags: c++, networking, tcp

I have a strange issue with a TCP server that sometimes hangs. The weird issue is that when it hangs it does not receive any new connection, i.e. doesn't respond to the initial TCP SYN packet. I was pretty sure that since TCP handshakes are handled by the kernel, even when a program hangs clients should still at the very least receive the initial SYN,ACK. If anyone knows a situation where a program can hang in a way that prevents the OS from even completing the TCP handshake (and without it ever closing the listening socket) please let me know.

P.S.
The program is written in C++ and the OS is Windows Server 2016.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but that sounds like it was a bug somewhere. Please, extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, re-take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the listen queue is full. Not responding to the initial SYN causes the other side to try another SYN a bit later. With luck, the listen queue won't be full at that time. The program is probably not calling `accept` (or some similar function) often enough.

It's also possible that  the program is using the selective accept functionality (see the `lpfnCondition` parameter to [WSASelect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaaccept)) to choose not to respond to this connection attempt.

Comment: Seems that it does listen(s, 5). Basically it means that there are 5 pending connections that were not yet accepted, is that correct?

Comment: Most likely, yes.